# "sagen" in "The news/article/post says ..."

Tags: verb, usage

> "The news/article/post says ..."

Is it correct to say

> (a) Der Spiegel sagt, dass ...
>
> (b) Der Artikel sagt, dass ...
>
> (c) Die (Facebook-)Post sagt, dass ...

or should the verb "sagen" not be used here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common way to talk about pieces of writing is using the verb "stehen"

> In dem Artikel steht, dass...
>
> Auf Seite 3 steht, dass...
>
> Ich habe einen Flyer und da steht, dass...

Comment: Can I also say "Auf dem (Facebook-)Post steht, dass ..."?

Comment: @boaten: "_In_ dem Post steht, dass..." would be more correct. Basically, if you have to open it, stuff is written _in_ it (think letters/'Briefe').

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it is not inherently wrong to use *"sagen"* as in your examples, however, it sounds a bit strange to me since *"sagen"* is commonly used in conjunction with real persons:

> Der Autor des Artikels sagt, dass
>   Der Spiegel-Autor Max Mustermann sagt, dass

Nevertheless, you can sometimes see *"Die Bild sagt"* in headlines, but usually not in texts of higher level.

In contrast, the verbs *"aussagen"* and *"besagen"** do work with things. Note that both have slightly different meanings though!

> (b) Der Artikel sagt aus, dass
>   (b) The article declares/states that
>
> (c) Der (Facebook-)Post besagt, dass
>   (c) The (facebook) post indicates that

Note: it is *der Post* (with an English pronunciation) if meant as a contribution or a post on a website.

---

*) The same also applies to *"absagen"*.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest a more formal alternative

> Laut X

literally *according to X*. You don't have to use it every time but it's handy to mix things up. *Laut* is usually used in reference to a scientist or study or something similar.

Comment: Please consider to mention the case needed for X, where you can choose between genitive and dative.